# Fibonacci in Prolog - Breaks if False

Tags: prolog, fibonacci

I have a program fib(X,Y). If Y is the Xth Fibonacci number it returns `True` else it should return `False`. My program breaks anytime I input statement which is false.

```
fib(R,V) :- fib(0,1,R,V).
fib(X, Y, 0, V) :- Y == V.
fib(X, Y, R, V) :- Z is X + Y, C is R - 1, fib(Y, Z, C, V).

fib(0,1) -> True
fib(1,1) -> True
fib(2,2) -> True
fib(3,3) -> True
fib(4,5) -> True

fib(3,5) -> Won't finish.
```

What do I do wrong? I am using https://swish.swi-prolog.org/ to run my program queries.

Comment: Did you try doing a `trace` to see what's happening? You might also want to consider: what happens if `R < 0`? Your second `fib/4` clause is still going to execute.

Comment: How do I run trace?

Comment: Enter `trace.` Then run your query. It's explained in the Prolog documentation. When you don't want to trace any more, enter `notrace.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you write two clauses `fib(X, Y, 0, V) :-` and `fib(X, Y, R, V) :-`. Prolog uses *backtracking*: in case one clause has been tried, it wil - regardless of sucess or failure - also later retry the next clause (there are some meta-predicates like `once/1` that can alter this).

So even if `R` is `0`, or lower, Prolog will also try the second clause.

A quick way to fix this is by using a guards for the second clause:

```
fib(_, Y, 0, V) :-
    Y == V.
fib(X, Y, R, V) :-
    R > 0,
    Z is X + Y,
    C is R - 1,
    fib(Y, Z, C, V).
```

Furthermore your code is not very elegant in the sense that you can not use the relation in a reversed way, nor can we query for the *X*-th element.

For instance you use `Y == V`, but this blocks unification: if we want to know the *X*-th fibonacci number, we want a way to propagate the result back. So we can use unification instead:

```
fib(_, V, 0, V).
fib(X, Y, R, V) :-
    R > 0,
    Z is X + Y,
    C is R - 1,
    fib(Y, Z, C, V).
```

But now we still do not have a bidirectional relation: we can not obtain the *X* for a given value *V*. This is more complex. The easiest way is probably using `clpfd` for this:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

fib(_, V, 0, V).
fib(X, Y, R, V) :-
    R #> 0,
    V #>= Y,
    Z is X + Y,
    C #= R - 1,
    fib(Y, Z, C, V).
```

Now we can:

1. enumerate all indices and the corresponding Fibonacci numbers:

   ```
   ?- fib(A,B).
   A = 0,
   B = 1 ;
   A = B, B = 2 ;
   A = B, B = 3 ;
   A = 4,
   B = 5 ;
   A = 5,
   B = 8 ;
   A = 6,
   B = 13 ;
   A = 7,
   B = 21
   ...
   ```
2. Obtain the *i*-th Fibonacci number:

   ```
   ?- fib(2,B).
   B = 2 ;
   false.

   ?- fib(10,B).
   B = 89 ;
   false.
   ```
3. obtain the *i* for which the corresponding Fibonacci number is a certain value:

   ```
   ?- fib(A,1).
   A = 0 ;
   A = 1 ;
   false.

   ?- fib(A,2).
   A = 2 ;
   false.

   ?- fib(A,3).
   A = 3 ;
   false.

   ?- fib(A,4).
   false.

   ?- fib(A,5).
   A = 4 ;
   false.
   ```
4. Check if the *i*-th Fibonacci number is a given value:

   ```
   ?- fib(4,5).
   true ;
   false.

   ?- fib(4,6).
   false.

   ?- fib(4,10).
   false.

   ?- fib(5,8).
   true ;
   false.
   ```